# Present multiple Images in fullscreen

Tags: ios, image, fullscreen

I'm looking for the name of the class Apple uses to present a number of Images in full screen (similar to the AppStore-App on iPad when you tap the preview images of any App. In the bottom of the view is a bar with little preview Images from all the Images).

If this is a public class, how is it called and is it available for iPhone as well?

Comment: No, you have to build it yourself. But it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer... I wonder why Apple wants developers to build their own image-fullscreen-presenter although it is needed very often. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Because they are lazy. ;) Sorry, but is this a real question? Have you ever build an application before on any other platform? On most platforms you have to build nearly everything yourself. It's extraordinary that you have so much you can use in iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have created my own `ImageFullScreenPresenter`.
What is important for anybody trying to build their own `ImageFullScreenPresenter` is to make it a subclass of `UIViewController`.

```
  PKImageFullScreenPresenter *pkImageFullScreen = [[[PKImageFullScreenPresenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"PKImageFullScreenPresenter" bundle:nil imageArray:myImageArray] autorelease];
        AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        UIViewController     *rootViewController;
        if (DEVICE_IS_IPAD) {
            //since the splitviewcontroller is the rootviewcontroller on ipad i set it as my temporary rootViewcontroller for ipad
            rootViewController  = appDel.splitViewController;
        }
        if (DEVICE_IS_IPHONE) {
            //on iphone i need the tabbarcontroller as temporary rootviewcontroller
            rootViewController  = appDel.tabBarController;
        }
        //set the alpha to zero, so it can fade in animated
        pkImageFullScreen.view.alpha    = 0;
        //save the temporary rootViewController, so I can set it back when dissmissing the ImageViewController
        pkImageFullScreen.superViewController       = rootViewController;

        //hide the status bar
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

        //setting black backgroundcolor
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        //init the fullscreencontroller as rootview
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pkImageFullScreen] autorelease]];
//smooth fade animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f
                         animations:^(void){
                             pkImageFullScreen.view.alpha = 1;
                         }];
```

Doing so, allows me to present the `ImageFullScreenPresenter` on iPhone and iPad, no matter you are using a window-based app, a splitViewController on iPad or whatever.
When dismissing the ImageFullScreenPresenter i set the temporary saved rootViewController back with an animation:

```
- (void)closeView:(id)sender{
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f
                     animations:^(void){
                         self.view.alpha = 0;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //show the statusbar again
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
                         //setting the statusbarstyle
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
                         //set the backgroundcolor for the window
                         [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.backgroundColor = GLOBAL_TINT_COLOR; //my custom color vor all GUI Objects
                         //set the temporary rootViewController back
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:superViewController];

                         //sometimes the navigationbar hides the statusbar, the following two lines help me out
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

                     }];

}
```

I dont know if this is the right way to go, but it works perfectly finefor me. I do not have to worry abput any rotation issues like I would have when i directly add this to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`.

I hope this helps others who try do achieve the same :)